# "A" record redirect gives 400 Bad Request in nginx

Tags: nginx, http, domain-name, url, namecheap

I've registered a domain with NameCheap and have set up an A redirect to my web server. Visiting the server directly (`http://1.2.3.4`) is fine, but going through the domain name returns `400 Bad Request` from nginx.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here's the relevant part of the nginx config file.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
   location /tile/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:20008;
   }
   location /datasource/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:20008;
   }
   location /maps {
     alias   /usr/share/nginx/www/Project-OSRM-Web/WebContent/;
   }
   location /tilemill {
       rewrite     ^(.*)$ http://<myhardcoded IP address>:5002 permanent;
   }

   location / {
     alias   /usr/share/nginx/www/Project-OSRM-Web/WebContent/;
   }

}
```

No entries appear in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

EDIT

More information: even with debugging switched on, nothing shows up in error.log when accessing mydomain.org - not a single line of output. However, accessing www.mydomain.org (which is set up identically at namecheap) works, and produces many pages of output.

Hmm. Ok, it's finally working. Shutting down nginx, waiting a minute, then starting it again did the trick. Previously I had been using `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Have you checked that the name is resolving to the correct IP using `nslookup`?

Comment: Yes, it is. (4 more to go)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for being unable to comment as I am a new user.

Have you tried all of the locations?

For example, since /maps is locally stored, perhaps it would work while /datasource and /tile might not because of the proxy pass.

Please post the results from testing each one of your URLs.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. I hadn't tried any of the other URLs until now since the main one failed. Now, actually `www.mydomain.com/maps/` does work, so it's just `/` that doesn't work. (Which is strange, because the two have the same definition.)

Comment: Ok, strangely the problem seems to have fixed itself. Maybe something to do with DNS records?

Comment: Hmm, nope. It's weird. www.mydomain.com works (even if I leave `servername` as localhost). The IP address works. But mydomain.com doesn't. (Both www.mydomain.com and mydomani.com resolve correctly).

Comment: What is your proxy pass referring to (port 20008)?  Is it an application server or just another web server?